# Problemas ao resolver tratamento em loop

Tags: python, loop, while

Boa tarde a todos! Gostaria da ajuda de vocês pra resolver esse problema.
Esse miniprojeto está rodando no Repl.it e funcionando "quase perfeitamente" a não ser por um único problema:[image: Se for pressionada a tecla "n" para sair do programa, ele retorna ao loop]
Quando há a confirmação no programa se "Deseja continuar", ao responder "n" não consigo encerrar o programa, ele continua voltando ao loop inicial. Gostaria de alguma forma encerrar de vez o programa quando fosse pressionada a tecla "n" durante a pergunta.
Obrigado a Todos, desde já.

```
while True:
  print('*'*40)
  print('          BEM VINDO AO TABUPY      ')
  print('*'*40)
  tabuada = int(input('Qual tabuada deseja saber? '))
  inicio = int(input('Qual numero deseja começar a tabuada? '))
  final = int(input('Até qual número deseja a tabuada? '))
  
  for tabu in range(inicio, final+1):
    resultado = tabuada * tabu
    print(f'{tabuada} x {tabu:2} = {resultado}')
  print('-=-'*13)
  while(True):
    continuar = input('Deseja continuar? s/n ').strip().lower()[0]
    if continuar == 's':
      os.system('clear')
      break
    elif continuar == 'n':
      os.system('clear')
      break
    else:
      print('Comando INVÁLIDO')
      continue
```

Comment: Tu não estás saindo do loop infinito (while true) quando o usuário digita `n`

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado me perdoe, eu acabei colocando o código antigo nessa parte que vc viu, o codigo o certo seria o do print ( mas já atualizei o código). O problema é que resolvi colocar a pergunta " Deseja continuar " em Loop , e quando aperto "n" eu nao consigo sair do loop , pois ele já está dentro de outro loop. A minha dificuldade está sendo, encerrar o programa de vez quando apertada a letra "n", qualquer que seja sua posição( while dentro de while). Nao sei se consegui ser claro na minha explicação.

Answer (score -2):

uma solução é um novo laço para checar a parada e uma variável para controlar o primeiro loop:

```
import os
Parar = 1
while Parar:
  print('*'*40)
  print('          BEM VINDO AO TABUPY      ')
  print('*'*40)
  tabuada = int(input('Qual tabuada deseja saber? '))
  inicio = int(input('Qual numero deseja começar a tabuada? '))
  final = int(input('Até qual número deseja a tabuada? '))
  
  for tabu in range(inicio, final+1):
    resultado = tabuada * tabu
    print(f'{tabuada} x {tabu:2} = {resultado}')
  print('-=-'*13)
  continuar = '';
  while 1:
    continuar = input('Deseja continuar? s/n ').strip().lower()[0]
    if continuar == 's':
      os.system('clear')
      break
    elif continuar == 'n':
      os.system('clear')
      Parar = 0
      break
    else:
      print('Comando INVÁLIDO')
      continue
```

Comment: valeu @Junior Dante ! muito obrigado irmão, nao havia pensado nessa possibilidade de criar uma variavel pra while pra depois "desliga-la". Foi de grande ajuda!
ps: Não sei porque essas pessoas ficam negativando a publicação, negativaram meu topico, e sua ajuda. Na boa, to vendo que a comunidade aqui é cheia de mimimi pra avaliar tópicos.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado, se precisar de ajuda pode falar comigo, ficarei feliz em ajudar se for possível, python não é muito meu forte, mas qualquer coisa, tamo ae.